# Creating two services and connecting them

Tags: php, laravel, service

So I've been given a project where my ultimate goal will be to create two services, service A and service B, and use a messaging system to connect them to single business process.

Service A has two task:

- Accept HTTP request that carry money information
- Generate AMQP messages towards "Service B"

Service B has two tasks:

- Service accepts AMQP messages generated by Service A
- Service must have account entity stored in database, described by two properties, balance and updatedAt

I understand the basic concept of creating this project and doing these tasks for both services, but I don't understand how am I supposed to create these services. Should they be a separate project or I can create them in a single Laravel project? Is there a Laravel functionality for creating services? I've been reading a lot of stuff for a few days but I can't find a solution yet. If you can provide any info or instructions, I'll be thankful. If you need any more info about a project, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are thinking of using a micro service architecture, in which case it should be two different projects where the projects don't share any code or data and communicates only through messages or APIs.

Micro service architecture is something very difficult to get a hold of when we are always used to working on monolithic architecture. Few pointers,

1. Change our way of thought tied to database and joining data across tables to show data
2. Don't create separate services just for the sake of doing it.
3. Each service should be independent and should communicate to other services by exposing APIs or pushing/pulling data from some message bus
4. Micro services should be independently scalable (horizontal scaling)
5. Think of micro services as something which solves a specific business problem